# How does react handle - in css selector

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I have a css block

```css
.button-set {
/* css styles */
}
```

How do I use this on an JSX element using the `className` attribute

Comment: Does `className="button-set"` not work?

Comment: No, I did try that but reading the docs, the classname is mangled to prevent name collisions

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I didn't knew was that when importing a CSS module element like this returns a key value pair

```js
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
```

So I could very easily do this

```
<div className={styles["button-set"]}>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an external css file like app.css then just import it in the component (App.js) and try this.

for example -
App.css -

```
.button-set{

background-color:black;
 color:white;
}
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
function App() {
return (
<div className="App">
 return (
<div className="App">
    <button className="button-set">CLick me</button>
</div>


 );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const YourFunction = () =>{
    return(
        <div className='botton-set'>
            Your content here
        </div> 
    )
}
```

Comment: I did do that but that doesn't work. See my earlier comment for the reason why it doesn't work

Comment: It should work, anyway, Make sure you entered correct spells and camel case, like this ... className...... in which 'c' is lowercase but 'N' is uppercase

Comment: I have correctly checked all that. When I do import using this  `import "../styles/globals.css"`, I get this error ```./styles/globals.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Please move all global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global
Location: pages/index.js```